# Is there a way to see if a VBA function is used in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am an intern working on cleaning up a horrible, horrible mess of a calculator made with Excel and VBA.  I've never really played with VBA in the past, so this is all very new to me, so please forgive me if I am asking the wrong questions, I am here to learn!

The first thing I am trying to do is understand the order of operations in this whole mish-mash.  There are 12 excel sheets holding variables and tables for the calculator, and looking through them it *looks* like not all of the functions defined in the VBA side actually get called.  Unfortunately there are far to many cells for me to look through individually, so I was wondering if there was a way to do it from the VBA side in the editor (Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications) that comes with excel when you turn on the developer tools.

I have tried commenting out entire functions, then updateing the code to observe if it breaks, but besides comparing the new output to an un-altered version of the sheet cell by cell, well... it's not really feasable if I want to finish it this month =(.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-James

TL;DR:  Is there an easy way to check if a function is actually used in VBA?

Comment: Ctrl+F the function name? (Searching Current Project rather than Current Module)

Comment: Are there any comments in the code? Any headers indicating which block does what function? If not, it's going to be a job unless you know VBA well enough to dissect each line

Comment: Could always try the old way of commenting out a function and seeing if anything throws an error.  This can be tedious though.

Comment: @finjo Ctrl+F is the way I am doing it now.  Unfortunately there are literally dozens of functions I have to search for and 12 sheets to check through.  This was really poorly built...

Comment: @SeanKelly No, unfortunately there are no comments what so ever...  Fortunately VBA seems pretty straight forward, I'm just trying to remove junk and legacy functions that were used in development but not the current version.

Comment: @TrevorD Well that's the current plan unless someone can point me toward a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: There are ways to do like, cell-wise iteration and check *each* literal cell for function strings... `For each sht in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets: For each cl in sht.Cells: If Instr(cl.Value,<function name>) <> 0 Then...`

Comment: If you're trying to determine whether the function is used (called) *in VBA* (not *using VBA*), then you can simply comment the function and re-compile, if the function is used, it will raise a compile error.

Comment: There is a nice open-source project to extend the functionality of the VBA editor: http://rubberduckvba.com/ I don't know all of its features, but I would be surprised if it didn't include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: you need to find references to VBA functions in both cells and the VBA code.

You will need to do a "Find" (Ctrl+F) in both the Workbook and the VBA editor.

For the workbook, be sure the search parameters to the entire workbook, and look in the Formulas: 
[image: FindAndReplaceDialog]

For searching the VBA code, bring up a Find, and be sure to search all modules by selecting "Current Project":

[image: FindAndReplaceVBAEditor]

Buy stepping through these, you should find all references. It is still is a bit of work, but I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you find a function that you want to know if it is used, add something like this is in the beginning of the function:

```
Sub HelloWorld()
    Debug.Print "Starting HelloWorld()"
    ...
    ...
```

Bring up the debug window with Ctrl-G and then start testing your workbook. All methods that are reported are in use. All the rest - *perhaps* not.

Comment: Oh... that's a good idea.  I feel like I should have tried this first...  before I came here =/